# Batch add/import of a list of users to a group in Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

We have two lists of users (about 1000 each) that we need to add to groups in Active Directory (Windows Server 2003...one list will be in one group, one in the other). All the users currently exist in the directory, but we just need to assign them properly. Is there an easy way to do this without scripting? If not, can it be scripted with Ruby, Perl or Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scripting it in ruby. I'm not a big fan of Windows batch scripting and this way I could do it from my Linux box (my primary desktop). Hope it helps others:

```
require 'ldap'

conn = LDAP::Conn.new('ad-server-host-name', 389)
conn.bind('user', 'password')

puts "Connected? #{conn.bound?}"

group_dn = "CN=blah, OU=blah, OU=blah, OU=blah, dc=company, dc=com"

mod = [LDAP.mod(LDAP::LDAP_MOD_DELETE, 'member',     ["CN=test,OU=Test,OU=blah,DC=blah,DC=blah"])]

begin
  conn.modify(dn, mod)
rescue LDAP::ResultError
  conn.perror("modify")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use [ldifde](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677) to import users from an ldif file or [csvde](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327620) to import from a csv file.</strike>

The articles are for 2000, but they still apply to the 2003 versions.

Sorry about that, misread the question. What you really want then is the [dsmod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732406%28WS.10%29.aspx) or the more direct [dsadd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754037%28WS.10%29.aspx) commands. You can redirect a file or do a simple batch script like:

```
for /f %%i in (%1) do dsadd group <group_dn> -members %%i
```

Then call that as `add.bat <file_of_users>`

Comment: Thanks!...but I'm not importing users, as much as trying to add existing users to a security group...